# Conditional MDX Query to calculate sum and average

Tags: sum, mdx, average

I have a sales(SalesID, GoodsType, GrossSale, AverageSale). I was to write two MDX expression in MS Visual Studio SSAS cube's Calculation tab to calculate Sum of GrossSale and Average of GrossSale where GoodsType is "Food". If someone please write the MDX expression for  me?

Comment: I wrote this expression for sum but it doesn't work! 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].Sales
 AS SUM([Measures].[Gross Sale], [Measures].[Datatype] = "2"), 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Forecast'  ;

Comment: What do you want to sum? Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145484(v=sql.105).aspx, you will realize that `Sum` needs a set as its first parameter, and optionally a numeric expression as a second argument. Is `GrossSale` not already summed? Why do you want to sum it then?

Comment: I have data table. Where GrossSale and Datatype are column. Say in GrossSale I have (100, 200, 400, 130, 350) and in Datatype I have (5,2,6,8,2) respectively. Now I want Sum of GrossSale where I have Datatype 2. Then I have GrossSale = 550, that is 200+350. Because for Datatype 2, I have 200 and 350. Hope yo understand now.

Comment: If `Datatype` is an attribute, say in dimension `Dim`, and GrossSale a measure, then you do not have to do any summation yourself. In MDX you would just use a tuple like `([Dim].[DataType].[2], [Measures].[GrossSales])` and are done.

Comment: thts great, it works !! thts a lot :)

Comment: One more question, if I want to add 1 or 2 or 3 in the expression, how can I do that? Means it will SUM all GrossSale where I have DataTyoe 1 or 2 or 3. Bellow, expression doesn't work

([Dim].[DataType].[1 or 2 or 3], [Measures].[GrossSales])

Comment: I added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, you rely on the Analysis Services engine to do the summing for you. To get the sum for the measure `[GrossSales]` for a single attribute member `2` for attribute `DataType` of dimension `Dim`, assuming the measure is configured to use sum as its aggregation value, you can just reference it in a tuple like

```
([Dim].[DataType].[2], [Measures].[GrossSales])
```

and are done.
To get the sum for three different values, you can either sum the tuples, i. e.

```
([Dim].[DataType].[1], [Measures].[GrossSales]) +
([Dim].[DataType].[2], [Measures].[GrossSales]) +
([Dim].[DataType].[3], [Measures].[GrossSales])
```

or use the `sum` function as follows:

```
Sum( { [Dim].[DataType].[1], [Dim].[DataType].[2], [Dim].[DataType].[3] },
    [Measures].[GrossSales])
```

The first argument for `Sum` is a set, the second a numeric expression.

Comment: hello again,
is that necessary to have direct relationship between measure and dimension? Because I have to measures(Data, GrossSale) and one dimension(Datatype) and GrossSale has direct relation with Datatype and indirect relationship with Data.
I am getting value from Gross sale but not from Data. Can you please give me some hints?

Comment: First of all, that is a separate question. So you better post it separately. Secondly, it would help if you would describe exactly what you mean by "indirect relationship". Your data model, as well as the settings on the "Dimension Usage" tab of the Cube Designer in BIDS would be helpful.

Comment: @Tuhin if the answer was correct, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: ok sorry for irrelevant topic. now its relevant topic. if I have 3 dimensions(Datatype, Customer, Product) and one measure (GrossSales). so what will be the MDX query if I want GrossSales for ProductID = 1,2,3 and Dataype = 4,5,6 ? Here Datatype has relationship with GrossSales, Customer has relationship with GrossSales and Product has relationship with Customer. if you please help me. sorry I can't find any option to mark as answer!

Comment: @Tuhin to mark an answer as the accepted answer, click on the check mark on the left. And: Stack Overflow is not a discussion board, but contains questions and answers; hence, as soon as a new subject starts that is not covered by the original question and title, you should post a new question with a title covering the new question so that it can be searched and found easily by others.

Comment: the riginal post is here, if you please give me the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635584/mdx-where-clause-does-not-work

Comment: Can you please reply for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184954/how-to-calculate-conditional-sum-in-ssas?noredirect=1#comment71533524_42184954