# WHERE clause in calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am facing some problem to calculate values from comparing dimension's value. I have 3 dimensions (Datatype, Customer, Product) and one measure (GrossSales).

What would be the MDX query if I want GrossSales for ProductID = 1,2,3 and Dataype = 4,5,6?

Here Datatype has relationship with GrossSales, Customer has relationship with GrossSales and Product has relationship with Customer.

I am trying this but doesn't work

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].Forecast_Gross_Sales AS 
( 
    SELECT NON Empty [Measures].[Gross Sale] 
    FROM [Measures] 
    WHERE (
        [Data Type].[ID].[ID] = 4 
        AND [Chain].[Customer ID] = [Measures].[Customer ID]
    ) 
), VISIBLE = 1 
, DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Forecast' 
, ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Data Types';
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are just getting started with MDX.  There are some fundamental concepts that will help you get what you need. This [comparison of SQL and MDX](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2916/comparison-of-queries-written-in-tsql-and-sql-server-mdx/) might be helpful. MDX uses the where clause as a slicer (to select certain dimension members) rather than a filter.  You can't put *member = somevalue* in the where clause.  And you can't really use the where clause to define a relationship to some other table.

Instead, your where clause would be something more like

```
[Data Type].[ID].[ID].&[4]
```

Since I can't see your data model, I can't be sure, but I would guess that *[Chain].[Customer ID] = [Measures].[Customer ID]* is something that you want to define the the dimension usage of your cube rather than in the query.

Edit: Now that the question has been edited, it looks like you are creating a calculated member.  in this case there is no select or where clause.  It will look more like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].Forecast_Gross_Sales AS 
Aggregate([Data Type].[ID].[ID].&[4], [Measures].[Gross Sale])
, VISIBLE = 1 
, DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Forecast' 
, ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Data Types';
```

The relationship from the measure group through the Customer dimension to the Chain dimension is something that should be defined in the dimension usage. This is called a [Reference dimension relationship.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175669.aspx)

Comment: Hi,
I have tried in this way first, but don't have the result,
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].Forecast_Gross_Sales
 AS (
[Chain].[Customer ID], [Data Type].[ID].[ID].[2], [Measures].[Gross Sale]),
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Forecast' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Data Types';

according to your suggestion, I will have to get GeossSale from Measure, WHERE [Chain].[Customer ID] = [Measures].[Customer ID]. So I am looking how to write the MDX query or how can I solve it! if you please help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with [Chain].[Customer ID] = [Measures].[Customer ID]?

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to achieve GlossSale (from Measure). Here Customer(PK) table has has relation with Measure(FK) table but Measure doesn't have relationship with Chain table and of course Chain(FK) table and Customer(PK) table has has relationship. Hope its clear now

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have a relationship between the Chain dimension and your measure group?  This sounds like you may want to look into that rather than try to write some complicated calculated member to get around it.

Comment: Measure group doesn't contain any field of Chain dimension, this is the only reason. YES I also believe, this is complex one!

Comment: I'm confused by that statement since above you indicated that both chain and the measure group have some sort of customer id.  Also, it doesn't have to be a regular dimension relationship.  Check out this link and see if a referenced or many-to-many might be what you are looking for: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175669.aspx

Comment: oh sorry, I am describing again. Measure group has CustomerID and Customer dimension has ChainID. So Measure group has no relation with Chain dimension. So according to above, I need GrossSale from Measure group where Measuregroup.CustomerID = Chain.CustomerID and Measuregroup.DataTypeID = DataType.DatatypeID
is it clear now, please let me know!

Comment: That sounds like it is a reference dimension relationship then.  Your fact has a customer ID.  Your customer dimension has a Chain ID.  This is a very similar situation to the Internet Sales -> Customer -> Geography modeled in the link I provided in my comment above. I'm amending my answer to note this.

Comment: so do u mean if I create only the relation can give me the result? I don't need MDX query ?